# Using FTP.exe to get unknown contents from a directory

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ftp

My objective is in a automated way get all files from a directory through the FTP.exe, but I don't know the directory contents.

So to do that, I need somehow to use 'dir' to list the files and use as parameter by the 'get' to download the files.

Or use 'get' without using the name only the directory.

And after I got the file, I have to delete it.

att,
Alexandre

Comment: What happens if you use `mget *`?

Comment: @lit Works! When I use mget * they ask if I want to get the file, but I have to input 'y' (yes) for each file and I don't know how many are.

Comment: @lit And after I got the file, I have to delete it.

Comment: Reading is fun: https://ss64.com/nt/ftp.html

Comment: Significant fun can be had reading about the `-i` switch.